# Is there an option to convert file to .csv format in Android?

Tags: android

I retrieved and saved the call history details in the file format. However, I would like to know if we have an option to convert the file format to `.csv or .xls` or any other format.

Thanks & Regards,
Serenity.

Answer (score 1):

Using [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) in one of my apps.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing built into Android that converts data into CSV or XLS format. There are plenty of third-party JARs for this, though, that may work on Android.